# How to upload video from Django user profile?

Tags: django, youtube-api

I'm looking for a way to upload video from Django user profile. I'm using Django-Userena and would like to extend the user profile with a feature to upload short 1-2 minute video to the user profile. I would prefer having the video uploaded to an external video hosting service like Youtube/Vimeo (as I believe this will be much easier to maintain the Django project files).

The only django-package I find relevant to this is django-youtube (https://github.com/laplacesdemon/django-youtube) I seem to be running into some trouble with this app unfortunately.

I would like to know if there are any other similar Django reusable app that I can use to upload video to Youtube/Vimeo or any other ways which you guys use to upload videos from a user profile on Django.

I've read Youtube API docs on browser-based uploading and it's overwhelming me. Please be kind, I'm a Django newbie. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is less overwhelming that implementing the browser-based upload flow yourself, and it provides simple callbacks when the upload is complete (including an upload via a webcam) so that you can get the id of the new YouTube video:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget

If you can insert an <iframe> into your page than you could use the widget, and if you could run custom JavaScript on your page then you could register the callback to get the new video's id.